# Character ~ in Symfony config.yml

Tags: symfony

There are some configuration options in config.yml with character " ~ "

For instance:

```
fragments:       ~
trusted_hosts:   ~
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Nope.  ~ does not mean null.  Null means null.  ~ means to use the default values as defined by the specific bundle configuration.  Big difference.

Comment: No, in YAML `~` means `null`. And this is the value that is passed to the DI extension classes in Symfony. It's true that most bundles are built to use some default values when `null` is passed for a config value, but you need to build your configuration to act this way.